# Запятая рядом с тире

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед тире в этом предложении (из статьи о протестах в Иране)?

*То, что нам кажется бесчеловечным, немыслимым: жестоко убить ребёнка, чтобы натравить людей на полицию(,) – это стандартная работа для провокаторов на беспорядках.*

Answer (score 3):

Запятая нужна, она закрывает придаточное.

Закрывающая запятая остаётся, если дальше идёт слово "это" или его можно подставить.
Примеры из справочника Розенталя:
*Самое лучшее, что он мог сделать, — [это] вовремя уйти.

Кто виноват из них, кто прав, — [об этом] судить не нам.

Что это был за случай, в котором было столько неясного, — [этого] он припомнить не мог.

Единственное, что мне здесь нравится, — это старый тенистый парк.

Если же нет времени разбираться, как глобальные изменения влияют на нас, — [это] не беда.*